# Printing with aspt.net core

Tags: asp.net, .net, printing, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0

I need to make print content using ASP.NET core.

I was thinking of embedding on the client side, but in a web search, it seems to me that it is not a good option, because this printing should be done without a preview and can also be done on any printer, especially the thermal ones.

I am getting the option to print on the server side through C #, but the contents I found are using Api printDocument and I did not encotrei to install in asp.net core.

How to proceed before this situation? Does anyone know of another option or know how to install printDocument in asp.net core?